# Active Record acting weird

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Question am I doing something wrong with the following code?

**Controller Test**

```
irb(main):003:0> x = Notations.all.first
/Users/programmer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:354: warning: :timezone option must be :utc or :local - defaulting to :local
  Notations Load (1.8ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [notation].* FROM [notation]'
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Notations ROWID: 1, TYPE: "Q ", OWNER_ID: "00003", CREATE_DATE: "2017-05-31 21:32:06", NOTE: "\r\x00\n\x00R\x00e\x00f\x00e\x00r\x00e\x00n\x00c\x00e\x00 \x00R\x00F\x00Q\x00 \x001\x007\x005\x005\x002\x00-\x000\x001\x000\x00...">]
```

The above works and retrieves my row that I queried for.

but below I tried to get the data for x.owner_id from the above and it fails(which clearly owner_id is a column in the returned query above)

```
irb(main):005:0> x.owner_id
NoMethodError: undefined method `owner_id' for #<Notations::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fb83cecf288>
    from /Users/programmer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/programmer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:99:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):5
    from /Users/programmer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/programmer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/programmer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/programmer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/programmer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Why do you expect `all` to return one specific instance? It returns a list of all notations. You cannot call `owner_id` on a list, you must first choose a specific notation - for example, the first: `Notation.first`

Comment: That was my bad I copped the wrong command from my terminal it should be x = Notations.all.first @spickermann

Comment: Why did you name your columns in uppercase and didn't follow Rails conventions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. The column names of the db were uppercase, so:

```
 y = x.owner_id # failure
 y = x.OWNER_ID # success

 irb(main):004:0> x.OWNER_ID
 => "00003"
```

## Solution:

Using an initializer to use lowercase schema reflection:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServerAdapter.lowercase_schema_reflection = true
```

So now:

```
x = Notations.all.first 
    irb(main):002:0> x = Notations.all.first
/Users/programmer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:354: warning: :timezone option must be :utc or :local - defaulting to :local
  Notations Load (1.9ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [notation].* FROM [notation]  ORDER BY [notation].[owner_id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY'

irb(main):003:0> x.owner_id
=> "00003"
irb(main):004:0>
```

As you can see above adding the initializer worked it changed the columns to lower case. I agree with having my columns lower case in the first place. However I am unable to change them due to this DB is used with my company's ERP system

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? Or another question?

Comment: I have already suggested that above I will say if it's a new code please follow the standards to avoid disasters in future

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the attribute on `ActiveRecord::Relation` whereas you must be calling it on `Notations` instance

```
x = Notations.all
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Notations ROWID: 1, TYPE: "Q ", OWNER_ID: "00003", CREATE_DATE: "2017-05-31 21:32:06", NOTE: "\r\x00\n\x00R\x00e\x00f\x00e\x00r\x00e\x00n\x00c\x00e\x00 \x00R\x00F\x00Q\x00 \x001\x007\x005\x005\x002\x00-\x000\x001\x000\x00...">]

notation = x.first
#<Notations ROWID: 1, TYPE: "Q ", OWNER_ID: "00003", CREATE_DATE: "2017-05-31 21:32:06", NOTE: "\r\x00\n\x00R\x00e\x00f\x00e\x00r\x00e\x00n\x00c\x00e\x00 \x00R\x00F\x00Q\x00 \x001\x007\x005\x005\x002\x00-\x000\x001\x000\x00...">

notation.owner_id
#=> "00003"
```

**NOTE:** Whereas the above code must be working for you I will suggest few changes as per the ruby standard

1. Model name must be singular `Notation` instead of `Notations`
2. column names must be in lowercase `owner_id` instead of `OWNER_ID`

Comment: That still doesn't work I found out what caused it @Deepak Mahakale

Comment: I answered it below it has something to do with the case sensitivity do you know if ActiveRecord can ignore case? @Deepak Mahakale